# How to get the latest updated data on VueJs?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm new to Vuejs and still figuring out how to get the latest updated data.

app.js - preload the data after calling 'global/checkUserSignedIn'

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import axios from 'axios'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'
import { sync } from 'vuex-router-sync'
import App from 'components/app-root'
import { mapGetters, mapActions } from 'vuex'
Vue.prototype.$http = axios

sync(store, router)

const app = new Vue({
store,
router,
...App,
created() {       
    this.preload()
},
methods: {
    preload: function () {
        this.$store.dispatch('global/checkUserSignedIn')
       }
   }
})

export { app, router, store }
```

global.js  (a vuex store)

```
 /// actions, mutations here
    const actions = {

    checkUserSignedIn({ commit, state }) {

        commonApi.isUserSignedIn().then(function (data) {            
            state.usersignedin = data
        })
    },
   }
    const getters = {            
        isUserSignedIn: state=>state.usersignedin
    }

    export default {
        state,
        getters,
        actions,
        mutations,
        namespaced: true

}
```

On a component, I call:

```
 export default {

        computed: {                
            ...mapGetters('global', ['isUserSignedIn']),              

        },
       watch: {          
        isUserSignedIn: function (newVal, oldVal) {
            if (newVal !== undefined) {
                 console.log('ok, correct result') 
            }
        }
    },
        updated() {
            this.$nextTick(function () {
                // Code that will run only after the
                // entire view has been re-rendered
                console.log('updated: ' + this.isUserSignedIn)
            })

        },
        created() {
            console.log('created :' this.isUserSignedIn)

            }
        }

    }
```

On both Updated and Created, I don't get the last updated data isUserSignedIn which is True if a user has been logged in though if I put **{{isUserSignedIn }}** on a template, it shows correctly.

Is there any way to get it to work other than having to use a Watcher here.

[image]

Updated: Maybe using Watcher is the only way to get the lastest updated data.

Comment: but it shows that updated is correct once it's updated? I would imagine that the problem in create is that you're effectively rendering the component before it has been updated, so in the `created` hook it will still be false. You can try instead of calling `preload()` on `created` call it on `beforeMount()` (or `beforeCreated()` but here you won't have any data watching/ready - which might not be a problem since you're calling into a vuex store that should be independent)

Comment: thanks for your help. beforeCreated() somehow shows undefined even data is from Vuex store, beforeMount() no luck as well. However with a watcher, I can check if I get a latest data.

Comment: But the thing to do on `beforeMount()` i the call to `this.preload()` on the main instance, not in the component